# how to make an if else statement that checks if a textbox contains a specific string

Tags: java, awt

Trying to make a login form in Java & AWT. the instructions said that the only valid username and password is "name" and "12345" respectively. How do I make an if else statement that checks if the textboxes contain those specific strings?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
            Frame fm= new Frame ("My Login Form");
            fm.setSize (600,400);
            fm.setLayout (null);
            fm.setVisible (true);
            
            Label lblUsername= new Label("Username");
                lblUsername.setBounds(40,40,100,50);
                fm.add(lblUsername);
            
            TextField txtName,txtPass;
             
             txtName = new TextField();
                txtName.setBounds (150,50,200,25);
                fm.add(txtName);
             
            Label lblPassword= new Label ("Password");
                lblPassword.setBounds (40,80,100,50);
                fm.add(lblPassword);
            
              txtPass = new TextField();
                txtPass.setBounds (150,100,200,25);
                fm.add(txtPass);   
            
            Button btnLogin,btnClear,btnExit;
            
            btnLogin= new Button("Login");
                btnLogin.setBounds (40,120,60,35);
                fm.add(btnLogin);
                btnLogin.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
                    
                if ( txtName.contains("name") && lblPassword.contains("12345"))
                { 
                }
                else
                {
               
                }
            }); 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since *txtName* and *lblPassword* are not strings but *TextField* and *Label* objects respectively, you have to use Java's methods **getText()** and **equals()** to check that the text values are identical. Using **==** instead of **equals()** will compare the strings' memory addresses instead of the text they contain, so they will always be different. This *if* statement should work fine:

```
if (txtName.getText().equals("name") && lblPassword.getText().equals("12345"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close to your solution.
Instead of using contains, use == .

Contains will return true for "name123" and  "name" as well. You need to strictly check "name" only.

Check the below code:

```
if ( txtName == "name" && lblPassword == "12345")
{ 
// match successfull
}
else
{
 // throw error           
}
```

You can also nest the if condition if you want:

```
 if ( txtName == "name")
  if (lblPassword == "12345")
    { 
    // match successfull
    }
    else
    {
     // throw error           
    }
```

Comment: I get an error saying Textfield and String are incompatible types now

Comment: Use getText() function to get the value from the textField.
like this -> 
txtName.getText() == "name"